# Best moment to detect collisions in game loop

Tags: collision-detection

Consider a game loop like this:

```
while (gamerunning) {
    if (it is time to update physics)
        update(fixedTickDuration);
    alpha = percent of tick elapsed;
    draw(alpha);
}
```

The update function moves objects based on their velocity etc., and currently also does collision handling. The draw function interpolates between the previous and current entity states to draw an intermediate representation. It is always behind by one frame.

Question: Should we instead do the collision detection and handling in the draw function using the entities interpolated coordinates? This handling in the draw function could alter further what would be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

No, for a few reasons, mainly that you don't want to rely on the rendering speed for game updates. You can fix the game update frame rate to whatever is appropriate and allow render rate to vary based on the processing environment (faster or slower depending on capabilities).

Example of constant game speed independent of variable FPS:

```
while( game_is_running ) {
    loops = 0;
    while( GetTickCount() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {
        update_game();
        next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
        loops++;
    }

    interpolation = float( GetTickCount() + SKIP_TICKS - next_game_tick )
                    / float( SKIP_TICKS );
    display_game( interpolation );
}
```

Code from this very nice overview of game loop considerations:

http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/